# Deployment of Diego after CloudFoundry on OpenStack with Bosh

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

Should I extend the deployment manifest of CloudFoundry to add Diego Releases or should I create a new deployment manifest for diego beside the CF manifest? I work with Bosh to deploy on OpenStack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely up to you, the main considerations are:

- In the short term, the scripts/tools for deploying Diego work in the context of generating two separate manifests, one for `cf-release` and one for `diego-release` (and `etcd-release` and `garden-linux-release`).  For example, you can see [this story](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/1003146/stories/107891444) in the Diego roadmap which takes a `-c` flag which is a path to an existing `cf-release` deployment manifest.
- Having both in one deployment makes certain operational considerations much easier. For instance, the `consul_agent` is colocated with most of the jobs from both `cf-release` and `diego-release`.  You will typically want the same version of `consul_agent` deployed across the board, but if you have two different deployment manifests, then you have to make sure to update the release reference in both manifests and `bosh deploy` both manifests.  And if one of your deploys stalls in the middle for some unrelated reason, then it can become increasingly complicated to reason about what state the cluster is in, and what steps you as an operator need to take.